# .htaccess rewrite rule for tricky url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I haven't touched .htaccess for years since switching over to nginx, but I have this site using good ol' Apache. I need to rewrite it's rather unorthodox URL (due to AJAX) to a clean one.

It currently looks like this:

```
site.com/#!products/desserts/35/carrot-cake/
```

But preferably I want it to read..

```
site.com/products/desserts/carrot-cake
```

With that said, what's the simplest way of taking away the **#!** and **/35/** in this? The number 35 represents the ID of the product, but that could be catched via it's alias **carrot-cake** anyway.

I tried using the rewrite generators out there, but it seems they have a hard time grabbing this kind of URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing you can do in htaccess here. Everything after the `#` is the URL Fragment, and that's never sent to the server.

So when the browser goes to: `site.com/#!products/desserts/35/carrot-cake/`, the only thing apache sees is a request for `/`, which means there's nothing you can do in htaccess that can change the fragment.

You'll need to do something on the client side if you want to make the URL look differently.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll solve it client-side.